# Does Windows 8 work well with Oracle Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8, guest-additions

In particular, I have Ubuntu running on a Virtualbox VM. I want to know if it will still work if I upgrade my Windows 7 host computer to Windows 8.

In addition to still running Ubuntu properly, I want the *guest additions* to continue working. *Guest additions* are what allows easy copy-pasting between the guest and host computers (sharing clipboard).

Comment: Since it's a supported host OS according to the site, why should there be a problem?

Comment: in case it does not fully work, eg. guest additions

Comment: I don't think they would claim that Win8 is a fully supported host OS unless it had that basic feature working properly. I see a whole bunch of Win8 related fixes in the changelog to improve support, so it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am running the RTM / Enterprise Evaluation (Build 9200) of Win8 and VirtualBox 4.2.4 r81684 on Mac OS 10.8 and am finding the experience a solid one so far. I do not have a Windows 7 system to upgrade, so my installation is extremely clean and the only bump I ran into was needing to [run the Guest Addition (drivers) for Win8 by hand](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#additions-windows) following the manual installation instructions.

The installation process has succeeded 4 times in a row as I experiment with different settings for the VM and display - so I would say you might dive in once you've made a backup of your existing Windows 7 setup and have time to upgrade. I know almost nothing about Windows these days and haven't needed too much research or assistance in getting things set up.

The guest additions actually fixed a display issue I had where full screen wasn't with the generic drivers that Windows installed. The guest additions made the OS much more usable for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Virtualbox says it will](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#idp8188112) run fine on Windows 8, though I haven't actually tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine. But if you go to "Add Windows Features", you can install Hyper-V, which is Microsoft's own virtualization hypervisor and works very well. You should be able to easily  boot up your virtual machine. Worst case, you'll want to disable any VirtualBox integration services on your VM guest before loading Hyper-V.

Comment: Bear in mind that the two virtualization techniques are not direcly comparable. Hyper-V is not as compatible with Linux and "fringe" distros as VirtualBox is. Also, VirtualBox is very efficient and has a number of features that Hyper-V lacks.